# If server response is just a simple JSON, then why there are 5 different resources showing in my network tab?

Tags: node.js, server-response

I am learning node and wrote a simple app which returns just JSON data as response.

There is no any error but I am not getting why there are 5 different resources (content.min.css, favicon.ico, jsonview-core.css, options.png, etc) showing in my network tab. Can anyone help me to understand this.

If possible how can I avoid sending these extra resources and just send the JSON data?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can't recreate that.

Comment: IMO you're using some browser plugin for json formatting and that's what's causing extra traffic

Comment: The favicon is being served up from your server. You can see it in your console. I would also agree about the statement about having a plugin running. I wouldn't worry about those things myself.

Comment: This is definitely a browser extension, try using in cognito mode. The favicon request is normal and can be ignored

Comment: Yes, it's because of one chrome extension that I am using. I checked in another browser, it's working as expected. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the chrome extension that I am using.

---

I found some interesting about `favicon.ico` file:

> Modern browsers will show an icon to the left of the URL. This known
>   as the 'favicon.ico' and is typically fetched from
>   website.com/favicon.ico. Your browser will automatically request it
>   when browsing to different sites. If your browser receives a valid
>   favicon.ico file, it will display this icon. If it fails, it will not
>   display a special icon.